# Android Account Sync Provider

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a Sync Provider account and all was going well until i click the account within the account settings. I'm getting the following error below in the LogCat.

[image: LogCat]

As you can see it is trying to get a 'resource' but what though? I have gone through my code many times and i cant find any faults any where...

This happens when i click the 'iSyncCRM' account in the image below.

[image: Account Settings]

If you need any code please feel free to ask in the comments and i will update the question.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woops.. I hard coded a name in one of the Xml's, so changed it to a String resource and it works...